# Hundreds of bots creating accounts using sign-in with Google

Tags: android, google, oauth2

We are getting hundreds of bots creating accounts using sign-in with google, like this in this format:

- Colin Bush: colinbush.81466@example.com
- Tambra Lockett: tambralockett.97742@example.com
- Marjorie Flowers: marjorieflowers.44615@example.com

In our Android app, whenever we release a new account, tens of bot create fake accounts and start sending random messages like "skgvbks" and also making fake reports by reporting users posts and favorite posts randomly. So we implemented a feature to check the Android device. We found that most of them are test devices, so we reject signup from test devices.

Also, we don't get a FCM token, we get instead BlackListed device. We also reject signup in this case. But now they are using real devices with legit FCM.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: a reverse proxy like Cloudflare has pretty good bot detection.